# Ubuntu remote login - different shells

Tags: command-line, putty

Why does logging into one account yield a shell with the name of the user, as well as color coded files/folders and the other shell in just "$" and only white text? See attached. I would like both sign ins to look like the left.

#### Putty Screens

[image: Putty Screens]

```
$ echo $PS1
```

- Left:

  ```
   \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
  ```
- Right:

  ```
   ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
  ```

Comment: Are you asking how to change the second user's login shell - or how to change the prompt string and LS_COLORS in spite of the different shell?

Comment: I would like to change the right shell so it behaves and looks like the left.

Comment: I would also `echo $PS1` for each (ie. show your prompt) in case they are setup differently. Yes it could be different shells are default for the different users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess you're using different shells.  What you see on the left is the default prompt for the Bash shell, and what is on the right might be the system shell: Dash.

To change your shell to Bash, try logging in as the given user and then:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Or as root (eg with sudo), try

```
chsh -s /bin/bash user
```

How you ended up with a shell other than Bash is another matter: perhaps that user was created as a system user or was created by some software directly modifying `/etc/passwd` instead of the usual `adduser` command (or even `useradd`).